# Send SMS to multiple recipients using Arduino & GSM shield

Tags: arduino, gsm

how Send SMS to multiple recipients using Arduino & gsm module. when button press send message to multiple recipients.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to set each number you are sending to as individual strings however i don't know what libraries/hardware you are using so you'll have to be more specific I'm afraid.

Comment: i am using arduino uno and sim900A module. i able to send message witone mobile no. but how Send SMS to multiple recipients.

Comment: i am using arduino uno and gsm module SIM900A

Comment: i am using arduino uno and gsm module SIM900A